# Understanding SNR effect on signal

Tags: snr, signal-power

I'm studying how SNR is measured, I know is a ratio between the power of signal and noise, and is given in a logarithmic scale but I'm confused about how is interpreted, for example does a SNR of 6 implies two times more power of the signal compared to the noise, than a SNR of 3?

Comment: Hello! Welcome here :) SNR isn't *always* given in logarithmic scale, but only when that's more useful. But: what you seem to ask seems to be more about decibel than about SNR?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it was more about how can I understand the decibel scale measured in my signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are taking about SNR 3 and 6 in dB scale then yes SNR of 6dB is double the power. In dB scale increment of 3dB implies doubling of power.